# Why are the minimum distances of a code and its interleaved code equal?

Tags: coding-theory

I know this is probably a very trivial question, but I am completely stuck. Let $C$ be a linear $[n,k,d]$ Code. Then the interleaving of depth $t$ is the Code $C(t)=\{(c_{11}, \dots, c_{t1}, \dots, c_{1n}, \dots, c_{tn}) \mid (c_{i1}, \dots, c_{in}) \in C \}$. Now I am trying to understand why the minimum distance of $C(t)$ is also $d$.

As far as I understand it, $C(t)$ is also linear. Hence minimum weight equals minimum distance. But (as the weights of codewords in $C(t)$ are sums of weights of several codewords in $C$) the minimum weight of codewords in $C(t)$ is obviously larger than of those in $C$. So how can the minimum distance of $C(t)$ be $d$, as well? Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, probably you already figured this out, but in any case if it helps someone:
The idea is that if $d$ is the minimum distance of $C$, then you can take a codeword from $C$ that has weight $d$ and then just add the zero codewords $t-1$ times to get a codeword of $C(t)$ that has also weight $d$, and you can convince yourself that this is indeed the minimum distance of $C(t)$.